# How do I find this volume using triple integral?

Tags: volume, solid-geometry

I have two cylinders $x^2 +  y^2=a^2$ and $x^2+z^2=a^2$. I need to find the volume **common** to both of them.
Now, I know that one of them has axis along $z$ axis and the other has it along $y$ axis. I am having trouble in visualising the limits of $x$ and $y$.

The $z$ must be enclosed within $0$ to $a$ and maybe y between $-a$ to $a$.
Please help in evaluating the limits for $x$ portion